# Stack overflow message

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, disk-image

I have created an image of my original hard disk and wrote that to a new disk in a new (different!) pc.  Surprisingly windows xp works and it seems to be working fine, but when we are running one specific application we get a stack overflow error.

However my original hard disk is working fine.

We don't know that program is written in which language. I have only exe file of that.

Can any one suggest, what may be the reason.

Comment: Please provide more information -- what operating system are you running? what program caused the message?

Comment: the copy must have been corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

This can occur when a process exceeds its stack. There are two main causes for this:

1. Too much data on the stack
2. Infinite recursion

Usually this is a bug in your application, regardless of it working fine on the other disk I would think that you have tripped something up.